# Pandas date_range to nested json

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to get a nested dict from pandas date_range. The keys of the dictionary should be the date and the values, a list of all values in the selected range. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import arrow

mymatrix = pd.DataFrame([
[pd.Timestamp(arrow.get('01-01-2017 01:01:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').naive), 5],
[pd.Timestamp(arrow.get('01-01-2017 00:02:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').naive), 10],
[pd.Timestamp(arrow.get('01-01-2017 00:03:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').naive), 20],
[pd.Timestamp(arrow.get('01-01-2017 00:04:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').naive), 30]
```

])

and I want to get something like:

by minute:

```
 {
      '01-01-2017 01:01:00': [5],
      '01-01-2017 00:02:00': [10],
      '01-01-2017 00:03:00': [20],
      '01-01-2017 00:04:00': [30]
 }
```

by hour:

```
 {
      '01-01-2017 01': [5],
      '01-01-2017 00: [10, 20, 30]
 }
```

is for large dataset so I want to avoid loops, I would like to do this directly in pandas/numpy.

can anybody help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what arrow is but I would try and keep everything in pandas/numpy.

```
mymatrix = pd.DataFrame([
[pd.Timestamp('01-01-2017 01:01:00'), 5],
[pd.Timestamp('01-01-2017 00:02:00'), 10],
[pd.Timestamp('01-01-2017 00:03:00'), 20],
[pd.Timestamp('01-01-2017 00:04:00'), 30]])
```

You can then set the index and use `resample`.

```
df = mymatrix.set_index(0)

                      1
0                      
2017-01-01 01:01:00   5
2017-01-01 00:02:00  10
2017-01-01 00:03:00  20
2017-01-01 00:04:00  30

df.resample('H').apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).to_dict()[1]

{Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): [10, 20, 30],
 Timestamp('2017-01-01 01:00:00'): [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [46]: x
Out[46]:
                    0   1
0 2017-01-01 01:01:00   5
1 2017-01-01 00:02:00  10
2 2017-01-01 00:03:00  20
3 2017-01-01 00:04:00  30

In [47]: x.groupby(x[0].dt.minute)[1].apply(list)
Out[47]:
0
1     [5]
2    [10]
3    [20]
4    [30]
Name: 1, dtype: object

In [48]: x.groupby(x[0].dt.hour)[1].apply(list)
Out[48]:
0
0    [10, 20, 30]
1             [5]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```